# Sticky nav bar, parallax flow, weird offset on 2nd div

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax, sticky

I'm trying to create a sticky nav bar/header section for a parallax scroll. The nav/header successfully sticks to the top of the page when scrolled down and up. However, when I click on the "Home" tab on the nav, the sticky nav/header section pulls down into the secondWrapper div section. What am I missing here? This is a link to the page so far http://www.jenniferpurwin.com/ThePartyNewYork/parallax-party.html

Javascript:

```
         $('.scroller').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var goTo = $(this).attr('data-goto');
                var top = $(goTo).position().top - $('#header_container').height();
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: top },'slow');                    
            });


            var sections    = {},
            i               = 0;

            $('.section').each(function(){
                var sectionName = $(this).attr('id');                    
                sections[sectionName] = {'bottom': $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight(true), 'top':$(this).offset().top - $('#header_container').height()};
            });


            $(window).scroll(function(){
                var $this = $(this),
                pos   = $this.scrollTop();                         
                for(i in sections){   
                    if( pos < sections[i].bottom && sections[i].top <= pos){                            
                        $('#header_container a').removeClass('active');
                        $('#nav_' + i).addClass('active');
                    }  
                }
            });


    $(document).ready(function() {
        var stickyNavTop = $('#header_container').offset().top;
        var stickyNav = function() {
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();     
            if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) {     
                $('#header_container').addClass('sticky');
            } else {    
                $('#header_container').removeClass('sticky'); 
                }};
        stickyNav();
        $(window).scroll(function() {   
        stickyNav();
        });
        })
```